# iPhone - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate inheritance

Tags: iphone, inheritance, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I have added a `UIImagePickerController` to a `UIViewController`. I have also assigned the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to that `UIViewController`.

When I execute the following line,

```
myPicker.delegate = self;
```

***Xcode*** gifts me with the following message:

> warning: assigning to
>   id
>   from incompatible type 'RootViewController'

Then I added the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol to the same `UIViewController` and the error message vanished.

So, do I have to add both protocols to the `UIViewController` when I add a `UIImagePickerController`?

If the `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` as stated in the docs, shouldn't this be automatic? Why do I have to add its parent's delegate protocol and not just the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol?

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As you noted, `UIImagePickerController` inherits from `UINavigationController`. It uses the same `delegate` property though and doesn't declare a (hypothetical) "imagePickerDelegate" of its own, so your delegate has to conform to both protocols. It makes sense, because you're also assigning the same delegate to the `UINavigationController` part (that knows nothing about the image picker).

The API design is a bit questionable here in my opinion, but anyway, all methods in `UINavigationControllerDelegate` are optional, so it suffices to declare that you conform to the protocol and be done with it.

Comment: it is illogical and breaks common sense, and the docs, as always, are vague as hell -  but I suspected the problem was something like that. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 33):

Add these code like below,you can see the warning disappear.

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> { }
@end
```

The Protocol of `UIImagePickerController` and `UINavigationController` must be added in your interface, this can make the warning invisible.

Comment: Thank you it helped me lot and solved the problem quick