# Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'CameraVIewController*''

Tags: objective-c, ipad

`Assigning to id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> from incompatible type CameraViewController*`  warning shows near `picker.delegate = self;` line

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if((UIButton *) sender == takePhoto) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
} else {
    //picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: [This][1] is the best answer that I founded for this question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727895/iphone-uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-inheritance

Comment: Now I noticed that you need to also assign your UIViewController to UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol, because documentation says this for UIImagePickerControllerDelegate:

@property(nonatomic,assign)    id <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate;

so it means you need to assign to both of these protocols.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation for `UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) says that the delegate must implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol.  Your `CameraViewController` either doesn't implement this protocol, or doesn't declare that it does so in its header.

Comment: Downvoted. You should also conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 83):

Note that you must conform to both the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocols to use the image picker.

Comment: This should be marked correct - Most people expect that UIImagePickerControllerDelegate is required, but overlook that it's asking for UINavigationControllerDelegate as well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why on earth does it need UINavigationControllerDelegate? That's a real mystery.

Answer (score 14):

Just add both protocols.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Then set the delegate obviously. :)