# UIImagePickerController delegate warning

Tags: delegates, warnings, uiimagepickercontroller

I've just put a photo picker into my project, and everything works fine. The only thing is it insists on giving me the following warning where I set the delegate -

```
Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'AddTargetViewController *'
```

I have set up the delegate in the AddTargetViewController.h in the normal way -

```
@interface AddTargetViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

and I can't see anything wrong. As I say, it works fine, and all the delegate methods fire off as they should.

```
-(void)takePhoto {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];

    imagePicker.delegate = self; // *** warning on this line ***
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is duplicate question to [iPhone - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727895/iphone-uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-inheritance).

In short your view controller has to conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in addition to `UIImagePickerDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks - you don't know how long I trawled this site for an answer to this, but I missed that one! I don't think it would be hard for Apple to make it a bit clearer, as it's not blindingly obvious (not to me anyway...)

Answer (score 3):

Along with your `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` just add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in your .h file and it should work fine.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the reason for that?