# multiple delegates give warning

Tags: objective-c, delegates, c4

This is not a serious bug I'm just wondering because XCode is throwing me a warning when I'm trying to do 2 delegates from one view.
my view interface declaration looks like this

```
@interface C4WorkSpace : C4CanvasController<UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

and then I have a UIImagePicker that goes like this

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
```

and a UITextViewDelegate like this

```
userNameField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
userNameField.delegate = self;
```

I'm rather new to delegates and basically all that code is made up by using code from somebody else so I'm not sure I completely understand the concepts of delegates.

The warning I get is: "Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'C4Workspace *const__strong'"

Is it that I need to delegate to something else then self? If so to what? Or is it a C4issue?

Comment: So which line exactly is giving you the warning? Your code seems fine, by the way.

Comment: the image picker one gives the warning

Comment: it's the one that's called first

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727895/iphone-uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-inheritance

Comment: I found that before but it didn't make any sense to me...

Comment: If you search for "UIImagePickerController delegate warning", you'll see a ton of results, and the answer seems to be the same: make your class implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Have you tried it?

Comment: The code you show looks fine, there must be a problem in the code you are not showing.

Comment: @BlackRider's answer is good, seems like you need to adopt both protocols.

Answer (score 1):

so the magic is just adding `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to the interface declaration. It looks like this then

```
@interface C4WorkSpace : C4CanvasController<UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

thanks everyone for the help in the comments!