# UIImagePickerController Delegate Warning - Incompatible type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, appdelegate, photolibrary

I'm trying to link my photo library to display an image in the UIImageView which will allow me to add filters, but when you select the photo and hit 'Choose' the app crashes. Below is the code I'm using; 
    - (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.delegate = self;

picker.allowsEditing = YES;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The error is in the line:

```
"picker.delegate = self;"
```

and is noted as *"Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'VSViewController *const_strong'*

Please if anyone has a suggestion on how to fix it or an alternate code that will operate, that would be appreciated.

Please try to avoid over complex language, I'm new to coding and this issue has been frustrating me for a while.

Comment: Have you included UIImagePickerController delegate to your .h?

Comment: I don't think so, what was the coding for that?

Comment: Under the VSAppDelegate.h or the VSViewController.h? I tried both but there was no '@protocol' in either

Comment: @JMarsh most likely meant meant `@interface`, not `@protocol`.

Answer (score 2):

Your class actually needs to conform to both `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` as well as `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. This is done in the class declaration:

```
@interface VSViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
/* ... */
@end
```

The reason for this has been covered here: [iPhone - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727895/iphone-uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-inheritance)

Comment: Where would the be entered in the project? The delegates or the .h or .m files? Do I need to add anything to the main file?

Comment: Is `VSViewController` a class that you've written?

Comment: Do you mean is it the one that I'm coding in?

Comment: My assumption is that `VSViewController` is a class that you have created and that it has a corresponding header file and implementation file, such as `VSViewController.h` and `VSViewController.m`. Is that correct?

Comment: I also assumed from the error you gave us as well as the code snippet you provided, that you are in fact coding within class methods of `VSViewController`.

Comment: Yes, I'm coding in the VSViewcontroller.m file

Comment: All right. The most common place to put the protocol adoption is in the header file. So, in VSViewController.h, I assume you have a line that looks like this: `@interface VSViewController : UIViewController`. You need to alter that to match the code snippet I provided above. You can read more about Objective-C protocols here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: Thankyou very much! I was able to fix that particular issue! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: For informational purposes, it is also possible to specify that the class conforms to a protocol in its implementation file instead, making its conformation private.

Comment: You're welcome! And it seems that you're new to Stack Overflow, so hopefully you don't mind a friendly reminder to mark the best answer you received as accepted. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In your header file, you need to conform to the protocol.

`@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>`

and then you need to implement the protocol selectors.

Read this for reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: To be sure, which one was the header file?

Comment: the header file is the one that ends in `.h` Also, @David Xu, you need to update your code. UIImagePickerControllerDelegate requires the UINavigationController protocol conforming as well.